# "Till death do us part"

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

Every time I see this expression, I can't help thinking it's grammatically wrong.

> Till death do us part

Is it grammatically acceptable? Why is it used extensively in this form?

Comment: The correct form is "Till death us do part" and not "do us", (according to [the link](http://www.eskimo.com/~lhowell/bcp1662/occasion/marriage.html) provided by Henry)

Comment: @Benjol: Right, but I think "do us" version is more common. A quick Google search brings 47,100 results for "Till death us do part" and 365,000 results for "Till death do us part".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The phrase is quite old: it was part of the Book of Common Prayer from 1662 (see http://www.eskimo.com/~lhowell/bcp1662/occasion/marriage.html).  (For all I know, it could be older even than that.)  But fixing it as the official language of a ceremony cemented the phrase in that form, even as the language changed around it.  It's probably best viewed as idiomatic; you wouldn't want to say something else using the same form without a very good reason, but that particular phrase is a widely recognized feature of the language.

(Note, by the way, that the form in the BCP really was with "till" rather than "until"; this isn't surprising, since "till" is actually the older of the two words.)

Answer (score 11):

It's the present subjunctive.  In older forms of English, most conjunctions took the subjunctive; thus we would see, "till the Son of God appear", "before I be put to death", "If it be the last thing I shall ever do", and so on.

Comment: Being present subjunctive does not explain why the pronoun is *us* rather than *we*

Comment: @nohat, why would you expect it to be *we*? It's the object of "part", with "death" as the subject of that verb. In modern English, the phrase would be rendered something like "until death parts us," not "until we part at death."

Comment: @nohat: the answer does not say anything about 'do part' instead of 'part', that is 'do/does/did' used in positive sentences for the sake of emphasis

Comment: The subjunctive and indicative there mean two different things. With the subjunctive it's an uncertainty, whereas with the indicative it's a certainly.

Answer (score 6):

All of the answers omit a key point, or at best imply it.  While "death" here is the subject, most people take "death" to be a temporal indication.  This is why they expect the pronoun to be "we": I promise to stay with you till (the time of) death.  Of course, it really means "until death separates us."

Answer (score 0):

Both (1) *till death do us part* and (2) *till death us do part* are found if you ngram-view them, but not (3) *till death do part us*, which is surprising since it would be the normal word order:

> **till** (conjunction) **death** (subject) **do part** (present subjunctive of 'do' + bare infinitive of 'part', emphatic form) **us [from each other]** (direct object of the verb 'part')

Structures parallel to these would be:

(1) as long as | you  | do | me | love (?!)

(2) as long as | you | me | do love (?!)

(3) as long as | you | do love | me

[Ngram Viewer for the 3 'till death…' sentences mentioned](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=till%20death%20us%20do%20part%2Ctill%20death%20do%20us%20part%2Ctill%20death%20do%20part%20us&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctill%20death%20us%20do%20part%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctill%20death%20do%20us%20part%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The do of "do love me" is different from the causative "do" of "do us part"

Comment: The "part" in "death do us part" is not a verb; it's an object-complement adjective. It has the same structure as "till death make us dead"; think "till death make us parted [from each other]" in a more modern structure.

Comment: @Zorf So 'part' is like 'apart' in your opinion. Any piece of evidence?

Comment: @Zorf: Romeo and Juliet: Good night, good night! / Parting is such sweet sorrow, That I shall say good night till it be morrow. (Act-II, Scene-II, Lines 188-189) 'Part' is a verb!

Comment: @user58319 Shakespeare isn't a good choice for determining a part of speech, as he is notorious for verbing nouns

Comment: Moreover, the book of common prayer was published not long before Shakespeare (he served Elizabeth and James, remember), so it would not surprise me that "do part" went from object complement to emphatic in his lifetime