# What is the meaning of “till death do us part”?

Tags: meaning, idioms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Till death do us part”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/till-death-do-us-part)

It's a English name of a forthcoming Chinese film. The Chinese name is “Best love”.

[image: Till Death Do Us Part]

Comment: In some ceremonies that have updated the wording to use less archaic phrasing, "Till death do us part" has been replaced by "Till death parts us" which might be easier to understand.

Comment: Related: [Till death do us part?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/till-death-do-us-part)

Comment: The original phrase is slightly different: "till death us do part".

Comment: @Cerberus I didn't notice there are a question before. but there're some diff. He actually know what this sentence means. I didn't know it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"till death do us part" is a part of some traditional wedding vows.

The signifies that the married couple intend to spend the remainder of their lives together - They will be parted only by death

[part](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=part) - note that it is used as a verb in this instance.

> - S: (v) **separate, part, split** (go    one's own way; move apart) *"The
>
>     friends separated after the party"*
> - S: (v) **separate, part, split up, split,    break, break up** (discontinue
>     an    association or relation; go
>     different    ways) "The business
>     partners broke    over a tax
>     question"; *"The couple    separated
>     after 25 years of    marriage"; "My
>     friend and I split up"*
> - S: (v) **depart, part, start, start**    out, set forth, set off, set out,
>     take off (leave) *"The family took off 
>     for Florida"*
> - S: (v) **separate, divide,    part** (come apart) *"The two pieces    that
>     we had glued separated"*
> - S: (v)    **separate, disunite, divide, part**    (force, take, or pull
>     apart) *"He    separated the fighting
>     children";    "Moses parted the Red
>     Sea"*

Comment: do part = separate ?

Comment: @love: Yes. Two people that part would be two people that separate. In the context of this quote, it would be akin to a divorce or betrayal.

Comment: yep, part can be equated to separate in this instance

Comment: I've heard the vows rewritten as "until we are parted by death" which is a little more understandable

Comment: you must think: till death do, us part. so part is a verb in here. what i think is: there is only one clause, death is the subject, do is the verb, part is adj and a complement. is this OK ?

Comment: @MrHen: Actually, in the context of the wedding vow, the parting spoken of is death itself.

Comment: @snooze: "part" is part of the verb, just as in "I do know the routine" the verb comprises two words "do" and "know".  The original phrase is even "till death us do part", and it means "until death parts us".

Answer (score 10):

"Till death do us part" or "Until death do us part" is a common wedding vow. Its implication is that nothing other than one partner dying can end the marriage.

It can be used in other contexts but it will nearly always be referring to the wedding vow; even if it was spoken outside of a marriage ceremony it will imply a long-standing alliance or partnership between two people that is expected to last for the lifetime of those involved.