# Is it correct to say "Til death do us apart"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

I like the sound of the phrase and I wanted to make a shirt design with it. But as soon as I started googling for some existing ideas, I found that google and duckduckgo just refuse to search for "Til death do us apart" without quotations and change it to "Til death do us part". So I wonder if its grammatically correct to say "Apart" in this context.

Proves that it is correct are: movie "Til death do us apart" (2018) and various songs titled with "Apart".

Proves that "Part" is correct: the actual oath, wiki and various songs titled with "Part".

The problem with "Part" is it does not sounds as "cool" as "Apart" for me (personal preference), but at the same time I wouldn't do a shirt with incorrect spelling either.

UPD: The rewording of the phrase to "Until Death parts us" explains a lot. Thanks!

Comment: *Part* is used as a verb in "Till death do us part"; *apart* is, variously, an adverb, adjective or preposition. However cool it may sound, *apart* is not a verb..

Comment: Why do you think 'apart' is an appropriate alternative beyond "I just like it"? The phrasing has never used 'apart', that's why you can't find it. [There is some controversy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/till-death-do-us-part) over whether it should be "Till death do us part" or "Till death us do part", but there's no controversy about the last word, it is always 'part'.

Comment: @deimos: I believe you're thinking of "a part" in that case, not *apart*, which no dictionary I can find lists as a noun. In my first hasty comment I inadvertently and erroneously labeled it a noun, which is why I deleted that comment and wrote the existing one.

Comment: *til* is also wrong -  *till death do us apart* could just about mean *till death causes us to be apart*, but this is a very well-established set phrase, and it's just not a good idea to try to improve or rethink it. Some kind of play on words might work, but that's not what you are going for.

Comment: *Till death do us part* means *Until death does part us* or more modernly, *till death should part us*. I think the bare form of the verb that was once upon a time used for the subjunctive in *until* clauses is confusing people here.

Comment: I'd like to add that, although I can't find the movie you mention on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=till+death+do+us+apart&s=all), I see a few tv production that seem to be either an intended pun or Indian production where it might be an unintended mistake.

Comment: There are a bunch of movies (mostly short ones) called "Til death do us apart" and "Till death do us apart".

Comment: You can put whatever you want on a T-shirt. (There is nothing *correct* or *incorrect* about titles.) But most people would interpret *til death do us apart* to be a typo or an indication of poor English.

Comment: Ever been married?

Answer (score 1):

Cortesy to commenters, the phrase "Till death do us part" is a more fancy way of saying "Until Death parts us". Since we surely cannot say "Until Death aparts us", the whole original statement is *grammatically incorrect* which is the direct answer to my question.

Comment: I noticed that this answer is downvoted for some reason. Is it incorrect?

Comment: "Till death does us part" is the usual way of expressing this, as death is singular. Can you explain why you think it's ok to use "do".

Comment: @StuartF See my answer below on the origin of the phrase with a link to the Church of England webpage with the text of the 1662 marriage service.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "till death us do part" occurs in the Form of Solemnization of Marriage (the marriage service) in the 1662 Book of Common Prayer which was the only official prayer book of the Church of England up to the 1960s.

You can find the text of this on the [Church of England website](https://www.churchofengland.org/prayer-and-worship/worship-texts-and-resources/book-common-prayer/form-solemnization-matrimony)

The relevant paragraph of the service, which is spoken by the bridegroom and repeated by the bride is:

> I N. take thee N. to my wedded wife, to have and to hold from this day forward, for better for worse, for richer for poorer, in sickness and in health, to love and to cherish, **till death us do part**, according to God's holy ordinance; and thereto I plight thee my troth.

The 'N.'s, of course, are replaced by the couple's Christian names.

There was a British sitcom in the late 1960s and early 70s with the title "Til Death Us Do Part". I was never quite sure whether the switched word order was intended to avoid reference to the Prayer Book or a reflection of an error commonly made by the public.

Although this does not, strictly, answer the question I've posted it as an answer because there are many half-accurate and inaccurate statements made in comments and answers above and I thought that the true source and form of the phrase should be given with an authoritative reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a t-shirt that conveys the essence of the phrase, you should stick with - Til death do us part.

It's idiomatic, so you retain the meaning for the largest group of people by keeping that traditional phrasing, even if it's a bit odd grammatically.

It's often part of wedding vows, so maybe research that area for different uses of the phrase.

Answer (score -1):

It really ought to be "til death us does part", as it is death that is doing the parting, and death is singular.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, here "do" is present subjunctive.  see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/7823/9368